# Truncate decimal to specified places

Tags: r

This seems like it should be a fairly easy problem to solve but I am having some trouble locating an answer.

I have a vector which contains long decimals and I want to truncate it to a specific number of decimals. I do not wish to round it, but rather just remove the values beyond my desired number of decimals.

For example I would like 0.123456789 to return 0.1234 if I desired 4 decimal digits. This is not an issue of printing a specific number of digits but rather returning the original value truncated to a given number.

Thanks.

Comment: For a  pre-packaged function, try `plyr::round_any(.1234567, accuracy=.0001, f=floor)`

Comment: Using floor doesn't work for negative numbers when same problem is applied in a different context. E.g. -78.591553  and 79.859154 = -79 and 79 but I need -78 and 79

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
trunc(x*10^4)/10^4
```

yields `0.1234` like expected.

More generally,

```
trunc <- function(x, ..., prec = 0) base::trunc(x * 10^prec, ...) / 10^prec;
print(trunc(0.123456789, prec = 4) # 0.1234
print(trunc(14035, prec = -2), # 14000
```

Comment: But:
`trunc(1234567.2, prec = 5)` gives 1234567. Do we not want "1234567.2"?

Answer (score 4):

I used the technics above for a long time. One day I had some issues when I was copying the results to a text file and I solved my problem in this way:

```
trunc_number_n_decimals <- function(numberToTrunc, nDecimals){
numberToTrunc <- numberToTrunc + (10^-(nDecimals+5))
splitNumber <- strsplit(x=format(numberToTrunc, digits=20, format=f), split="\\.")[[1]]
  decimalPartTrunc <- substr(x=splitNumber[2], start=1, stop=nDecimals)
  truncatedNumber <- as.numeric(paste0(splitNumber[1], ".", decimalPartTrunc))
  return(truncatedNumber)
}
print(trunc_number_n_decimals(9.1762034354551236, 6), digits=14)
[1] 9.176203
print(trunc_number_n_decimals(9.1762034354551236, 7), digits=14)
[1] 9.1762034
print(trunc_number_n_decimals(9.1762034354551236, 8), digits=14)
[1] 9.17620343
print(trunc_number_n_decimals(9.1762034354551236, 9), digits=14)
[1] 9.176203435
```

This solution is very handy in cases when its necessary to write to a file the number with many decimals, such as 16. 
Just remember to convert the number to string before writing to the file, using format()

```
numberToWrite <- format(trunc_number_n_decimals(9.1762034354551236, 9), digits=20)
```

Comment: I used this for a while but its not working with a lot of different numbers, for example integers, NAN and more.

Comment: Thanks @Squeezie ,I just figured out this issue about the integers right now after reading your comment. Now the issue with the integers and many other cases which I founding testing it again is solved. Unfortunatly it won't make any miracles, but will avoid lot of pain when its necessary to write the resulting numbers in files.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way, but it'll work.

```
string_it<-sprintf("%06.9f", old_numbers)
pos_list<-gregexpr(pattern="\\.", string_it)
pos<-unlist(lapply(pos_list, '[[', 1)) # This returns a vector with the first 
#elements
#you're probably going to have to play around with the pos- numbers here
new_number<-as.numeric(substring(string_it, pos-1,pos+4))
```